# How do I get feedback on whether a MongoDB query succeeded and how many rows were changed?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB database and am using MongoChef to write scripts for it.  I have a script that reads in data from a collection and inserts the records into another collection.  The script runs fine, but I don't get any feedback on what occurred.  Is there a way to get acknowledgement that the script has finished running (that is, all the records are inserted)?  Is there a way to get an output of how many records were (in this case) inserted?  (I realize I could write another statement to count records, but I want to know how many records were actually inserted by the insert statement).  What I'd like to see is something like "Script successful. 1200 records inserted into collection properties."  Can someone show me how to turn on this output for MongoChef?  Thank you.

Below is an image of my script.  This is after it's been run.  Notice that there's nothing in the results tabs; there's no indication the queries have been run, that they were run succesfully or how many records have been updated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the MongoDb documentation for [WriteConcerns](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/) and see what information matches your Mongodb version. Previously the `getLastError` was used to get error information about the last executed CRUD statement. 
[getLastError](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getLastError/#dbcmd.getLastError) can give you information if there's any error occurred post execution of any CRUD operation.

You can also use the [WriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/#WriteResult) which is return by `insert`, `update`, `remove` and `save` operation to get the number of updated document. It also contains properties like `writeError` to get the information specific to that opeartion.

Sample(psuedo not specific to MongoChef) -

```
var wr = db.properties.insert(doc);

println("Updated %d collections of type %s", wr.getN(), type);
```

Comment: Thanks, I ran across WriteResult when I was searching earlier, but didn't know how/where to use it.  Can you give me an example of how'd I'd use it with the rest of my script?